# Is it normal Postgres query performance?

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql

I've got a table with ~2.4 million records. 
8000 subsequent selects by indexed field take ~2.0 seconds to execute (with only 5 values returned).  So it's about 4000 queries/sec which I found very slow.

The table is as follows

```
CREATE TABLE hashes
(
  id bigserial NOT NULL,
  hash bytea NOT NULL,
  ref_id integer,
  ref_loc bigint,
  ref_len integer
);
```

There's an index on the *hash* field.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ix_hashes_hash ON hashes USING BTREE (hash);
```

The *hash* column is filled with 16-byte unique values.

I run 8000 lines in one batch from pgAdmin:

```
SELECT id,hash FROM hashes WHERE hash=decode('04c04695137724288078eb81ac648841', 'hex');
...
SELECT id,hash FROM hashes WHERE hash=decode('632a1c158d1a470e4506b08a2e16d239', 'hex');
```

and it takes 2 seconds to execute.

Me research shows that:

1. [ProcessMonitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx) shows that the first run causes many disk reads. Subsequent runs don't cause any disk I/O, but still take 2 seconds to execute
2. Execution plan for a single SELECT query as returned by EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, VERBOSE):

    `"Index Scan using pk_blocks_hash on public."Blocks"  (cost=0.43..8.45 rows=1 width=25) (actual time=0.025..0.025 rows=0 loops=1)"
    "  Output: id, hash"
    "  Index Cond: ("Blocks".hash = '\373\355\341\264\200\234\210\3722\352\204L\252\355\021v'::bytea)"
    "Planning time: 0.175 ms"
    "Execution time: 0.076 ms"`
3. I can see a perf spike during execution of a postgres.exe process:
   CPU jumps to 25 %
   Memory usage jumps to 185Mb (from 6mb)
4. Changing index type from BTREE to HASH doensn't help  (however it reduces index size from 94 MB to 64 MB, but loses UNIQUE ability)
5. Surrounding the batch with *BEGIN TRANSACTION* and *END TRANSACTION* doesn't help
6. Modifying postgresql.conf as suggested by [PgTune](http://pgtune.leopard.in.ua/) (with restarting Postgres of course):

   ```
   max_connections = 20
   shared_buffers = 512MB
   effective_cache_size = 6GB
   work_mem = 64MB
   maintenance_work_mem = 1GB
   min_wal_size = 4GB
   max_wal_size = 8GB
   checkpoint_completion_target = 0.9
   wal_buffers = 16MB
   default_statistics_target = 500
   ```

   doesn't help.
7. Putting all requested hashes into a single query does help: I get only 330ms sec with:

   ```
   SELECT id,hash 
       FROM hashes 
       WHERE hash IN (decode('04c04695137724288078eb81ac648841', 'hex'),
                      ...
                      decode('632a1c158d1a470e4506b08a2e16d239', 'hex'));
   ```

   but it's not always possible to combine many queries in one and it doesn't explain slow query performance BTW.

Well, I'd expect not less than 50'000 of such queries per second.

**Do I want too much from this server? 
Or am I doing something wrong?**

The environment:

- OS:  Windows Server 2012 R2 x64
- CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-4170 CPU @ 3.70GHz
- Mem: 8GB
- HDD: 200Gb SSD
- Postgres: 9.5 x64

Comment: Why are you storing the hashes as a `bytea` and not as a `text`?

Comment: 4000 queries per second is 250 microseconds per query, which doesn't seem so large as an absolute number.  Nor should you be surprised that your queries have more overhead than just disk I/O.

Comment: Also: Postgres tends to work a **lot** better on Linux (especially because the Windows file system isn't as fast as those available on Linux). You should also [edit] your question and add the output of `explain (analyze, verbose)` for a single query. Maybe it's not even using the index. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: But running queries via `pgAdmin` is not particularly representative of what a well-written client application would do.  In particular, I would expect a client application to execute the queries via a prepared statement, but I see no reason to think that `pgAdmin` would do so under the conditions you describe.

Comment: Also: a Core i3 isn't really a good choice for a database server. How many cores do you have?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name , sorry forget the explain. It does use index scan and I edited the post.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, it has 2 physcal cores (4 logical). On another server with Intel Core i5 2400 (4/4 cores) the same 8000 queries take 0.9 sec

Comment: @John Bollinger, actually the server uses .Net API (Npgsql) and has even worse performance - it was 12 seconds for same queries (with v2.1). Switching to the latest npgsql  v3.2 did speed up the things 2 times - 5.6 sec.  Calling prepare() only once for a NpgsqlCommand and then executing 8000 queries just binding different parameter didn't help and even did the things worse - 7.2 sec.  So I came to pgAdmin just for tests.

Comment: @mistika: the plan **is** important because it shows the execution time **on the server** without the overhead of _transferring_ the data. And 900ms sounds way too high for an index lookup that is supposed to only return very few  rows

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, well, according to explain results of a single query:  (0.175 ms (planning) + 0.076 ms (execution) ) * 8000 gives 2 seconds.  Why does planning take so much time? Or is it ok for my CPU and I just need to significantly increase hardware requirements for the application?

Comment: I wonder if the issue you're running into is [the `update_process_title` issue](http://www.openscg.com/2016/09/improve-postgresql-windows-performance-by-100/).  Any chance you can disable that or upgrade to 9.6?

Comment: If you **really** expect 50000 queries per second you need a **lot** more power. Those queries will be executed concurrently and to be able to get that throughput you need much more cores then just 4 (serious DB server have typically a **lot** more cores then that). For that kind of throughput you need a server grade CPU (xeon or similar) not a desktop CPU and at least 64 of them.

Comment: @Bacon Bits, wow. Thanks! That gave me 1.6 seconds, which is 25% faster (5000 q/s  vs 4000 q/s), however still not as much as I'd like :)

Comment: I was told that Postgres on Linux works much faster than on Windows. So I installed Postgres 9.5 on Centos 7 with Intel Core i3-3240, 3.4 GHz (which is a little bit worse than Windows i3-4170)  and it did the same test with 8000 queries in 0.55 sec!  3 times faster than on Windows.